# How to determine SPI for Remote File Management on a SIM card?

Tags: apdu, ota, sim-card

I am trying to read and update some elementary files on a SIM. the question is what should be the SPI for a read/update command PDU? In other words, what privileges I need in order to update an elementary file on the SIM?

Answer (score 1):

3GPP TS 23.048 defines standards for doing remote file (RFM) and remote applet management(RAM). But keep in the mind that implementations may differ by each SIM vendor and access conditions to that file might be different than expected according to standard. Content and structure SIM/USIM files are defined according to 3GPP TS 31.102. For example in order to update SMSC address on SIM card , commands should be sent in the following order :

1. Select 3F00
2. Select DF 7F10 under MF 3F00
3. Select EF 6F42 under DF 7F10
4. Update EF 6F42

*Have a look section 4.7 to see SIM file structure from 3GPP TS 31.102*

*Have a look section 5 to see APDU packet structure from 3GPP TS 23.048*

Constructing the Update command requires the parameters that should be obtained from the SIM card vendor,

1. TAR (toolkit application reference)
2. MSL (minimum security level setting)
3. CNTR value
4. According to MSL value, KiC and KiD(OTA keys) might be required
5. SPI(Security Parameter Indicator)